# How to Select records of a certain format in MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

May I ask some little help on how can I get certain result format using my table design.

I have `T_EmployeeDTRLogs` table where the current design is the following:

```
| edl_EmployeeID |  edl_LogDate  |    edl_LogTime    |  edl_LogType  |
|     KMP0047    |   2014-05-05  |  07:35:12.1200000 |      IN       |
|     KMP0047    |   2014-05-05  |  15:06:23.3470000 |      OUT      |
```

Using the table design and given records I want to generate report or result into the following format:

```
| edl_EmployeeID |  edl_LogDate  |   In    |    Out   | 
|    KMP0047     |   2014-05-05  | 7:35:12 |  3:06:23 |
```

I am having problem on how can I generate this kind of result.

Can I have some your advises and help on how to can I generate this report.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Thanks for editing and for correction..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
select ein.edl_EmployeeID, ein.edl_LogDate, ein.edl_LogTime as [Out], eout.edl_LogTime [Out]
from T_EmployeeDTRLogs ein
inner join T_EmployeeDTRLogs eout on ein.edl_EmployeeID = eout.edl_EmployeeID
and ein.edl_LogDate = eout.edl_LogDate
where ein.edl_LogType = 'IN'
and eout.edl_LogType = 'OUT'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really works! Credits to shree.pat18

Comment: I already managed to get given desired format using the script of shree.pat18. But I encountered problem if I have logs on a certain date for example on 2014-05-14 that having IN time record log but no OUT time record log. The result is it cannot generate the transaction records dated 2014-05-14 due to insufficient OUT time record. Please help, thank you very much.

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead to allow null values.

Comment: I already tried that but I get same result. I already solved my problem using the concept of script of Bogdan Sahlean and you script I manage to come up to this script:
select  edl_EmployeeId, edl_LogDate, 
      min(case when edl_LogType = 'I' then edl_LogTime end) as 'IN', 
      max(case when edl_LogType = 'O' then edl_LogTime end) as 'OUT'
from dbo.T_EmployeeDTRLogs 
group by edl_EmployeeId, edl_LogDate

Answer (score 0):

A simple group by can give you the results you want without self join:

```
select  g.edl_EmployeeId, g.edl_LogDate, 
        min( when g.edl_LogType = 'IN' then g.edl_LogTime end ) as in, 
        min( when g.edl_LogType = 'OUT' then g.edl_LogTime end ) as out
from dbo.T_EmployeeDTRLogs g
group by g.edl_EmployeeId, g.edl_LogDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but when I checked and execute the script. It return an errors and managed to revised the query. After revision, the result of the given script generates NULL IN and OUT.

Comment: I already solve my problem using the concept of your script. This is how I do it:
select  edl_EmployeeId, edl_LogDate, 
      min(case when edl_LogType = 'I' then edl_LogTime end) as 'IN', 
      max(case when edl_LogType = 'O' then edl_LogTime end) as 'OUT'
from dbo.T_EmployeeDTRLogs 
group by edl_EmployeeId, edl_LogDate